# rails cucumber tests failing because submit fields are disabled for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

**Situation**
I didnt ran my tests for a while. I am now running my tests with the `bundle exec cucumber` command. Of course many failed and I repaired them the last days.

**Problem**
But 6 tests out of 40 are failing for no obvious reasons. Executing them manually locally and on staging servers works according to the formulated expectations.

I reviewed what the browser was showing (`NO_HEADLESS=1`) and using `Then debugger` (opening `byebug`) to halt execution of the browser and reviewed the browser. Fails save screenshots + the HTML.

I figured out that on all this 6 tests the `submit` button is disabled hence clicking it in my `When` (eg `When I click on "Ausgangsrechnung erstellen"`) clause has no effect it seems.

**The cucumber test code**

(The test is trying to create an outbound invoice which should fail on uniqueness, which it manually actually does)

```
Scenario: Create out invoice with duplicate number will fail
  Given there is an out invoice
  When I capture a new out invoice
    And I insert valid data but set the same number of existing out invoice within a company
    And I click on "Ausgangsrechnung erstellen" button
  Then I should see "Rechnungsnummer muss eindeutig sein"
```

**Screenshot**
[Here is saved screenshot which shows the submit button being disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKr3p.png)

(I checked the HTML too)

**Solution ideas?**
Does anybody know why my forms out of a sudden gets deactivated during tests while it works locally and my test servers? Happy to provide more information. First time I am asking regarding tests. By the way: The tests were fully functional before.

**UPDATE 11.9.2023**
Based on @Les Nightingill comments I am adding the code outside of the test code. Since it was not mentioned, which code explictly I will naturally add the code for the one test I posted although very verbose:

*Model:*

```
class OutInvoice < Invoice
  validates :number, uniqueness: {scope: :company_id}, allow_blank: true
  delegate :tax_number, :debitable_bank_account, to: :company
  before_validation :set_creditor_id
  before_validation :set_bank_fields
  validates :debitable_bank_account_owner, :debitable_bank_account_number, :debitable_bank_name, :debitable_bank_number, presence: true, if: :debit_payment?
  validate :direct_debit_only_when_bank_account
  after_save :create_in_invoice_for_other_company, if: Proc.new{ frozenn? }
  after_save :store_physical_copy_on_freeze!, if: Proc.new{ frozenn? }
  validates :frozenn, presence: true, if: :booked?

  def generate_number
    # Todo repair
    ""
    #last_out_invoice = other_out_invoices.last
    # if last_out_invoice.present?
    #   last_out_invoice_number = last_out_invoice.number
    #   # Generating new auto increasing number until the new number isn't existed
    #   while number_exists_in_other_out_invoices?(last_out_invoice_number) do
    #     last_out_invoice_number = auto_increase_number(last_out_invoice_number)
    #   end
    #
    #   last_out_invoice_number
    # else
    #   "1"
    # end
  end

  def auto_increase_number(invoice_number)
    invoice_number.strip!

    case invoice_number
    when /\A\d+\z/ # is a number, eg: "1"
      (invoice_number.to_i + 1).to_s # increase by adding 1, eg: "2"
    when /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/ # is a string, eg: "pyramid"
      invoice_number << '-1' # increase by adding '-1' to the suffix, eg: "pyramid-1"
    when /\A.+([\-\/\.]{1}\d+)\z/ # is a string with number, eg: "pyramid-1, pyramid-1.1"
      special_auto_increase_number(invoice_number)
    else
      raise 'unexpected'
    end
  end

  def debit_payment?
    self.paid_via == 'one_time_debit' || self.paid_via == 'durable_debit'
  end

  def pdf_name
    "#{company.name_and_type} - Rechnung #{number}"
  end

  def endnummer
    s = debitable_bank_account_number
    "**** ******** ***** **#{s[s.length-3..s.length-1]}"
  end

  private

  def create_in_invoice_for_other_company
    if other_company.present? && !duplicate_in_other_company?
      in_invoice = other_company.in_invoices.build()
      in_invoice.number= number
      in_invoice.net = net
      in_invoice.vat_rate = vat_rate
      in_invoice.currency = currency
      in_invoice.issuing_date = issuing_date
      in_invoice.service_description = service_description
      in_invoice.to_be_paid = to_be_paid
      in_invoice.creditor_id = creditor_id

      in_invoice.durable = durable
      in_invoice.durable_until = durable_until

      # current company is proposing to the other company
      in_invoice.company_id = other_company.id
      in_invoice.proposal = true

      # Copy of company details
      in_invoice.other_company_name_str = company.name_and_type
      in_invoice.other_company_street_and_no_str = company.street_and_no
      in_invoice.other_company_postal_code_str = company.postal_code
      in_invoice.other_company_city_str = company.city
      in_invoice.other_company_fitaf_id = company.fitaf_id
      in_invoice.other_company_tax_number = company.tax_number # out invoice doesn't need tax number

      in_invoice.paid_via = paid_via
      in_invoice.paid_today = paid_today

      in_invoice.durable = durable
      in_invoice.durable_until = durable_until
      in_invoice.cycle = cycle
      if physical_copy.attached? # physical copy preceeds fitaf out invoice
        in_invoice.physical_copy.attach(io: StringIO.new(physical_copy.download), filename: "#{pdf_name}.pdf")
      else
        pdf_str = Home::OutInvoicesController.render(
          template: "home/out_invoices/pdf",
          layout: 'pdf',
          assigns:  {
            out_invoice: self,
            bank_account: company.bank_account_for_invoice
          }
        )
        pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_str)
        in_invoice.physical_copy.attach(io: StringIO.new(pdf), filename: "#{pdf_name}.pdf")
      end
      in_invoice.save!
    end
  end

  def store_physical_copy_on_freeze!
    unless physical_copy.attached? # without attachment attach current pdf permanently
      pdf_str = Home::OutInvoicesController.render(
        template: "home/out_invoices/pdf",
        layout: 'pdf',
        assigns:  {
          out_invoice: self,
          bank_account: company.mean_of_payment_for_invoices
        }
      )
      pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_str)
      # attach the currently live generated out invoice forever
      physical_copy.attach(io: StringIO.new(pdf), filename: "#{pdf_name}.pdf")
    end
  end

  def duplicate_in_other_company?
    other_company.in_invoices.where(number: number, other_company_name_str: company.name_and_type).present? ||
      other_company.in_invoices.where(number: number, other_company_fitaf_id: company.fitaf_id).present?
  end

  def other_out_invoices
    self.company.out_invoices.where.not(id: self.id)
  end

  def number_exists_in_other_out_invoices?(base_number)
    other_out_invoices.where(number: base_number).present?
    # ToDo check for number
  end

  def special_auto_increase_number(invoice_number, need_increase_previous_number=false)
    begin
      matching_parts = invoice_number.match(/\A.+([\-\/\.]{1}\d+)\z/) # get matching parts of invoice number
      special_character = get_special_character(matching_parts) # get special character that used for spliting string with number
      array_of_invoice_number = invoice_number.split(special_character) # get array of invoice number by special character
      index_number = 0 # init index number

      # loop through array invoice number in reserving order to modifying number part of invoice number.
      (0..(array_of_invoice_number.size - 1)).to_a.reverse.map do |index|
        next if !(array_of_invoice_number[index] =~ /\A\d+\z/ || array_of_invoice_number[index] =~ /\A.+([\-\/\.]{1}\d+)\z/)
        index_number = array_of_invoice_number[index]

        if index_number =~ /\A\d+\z/ && (need_increase_previous_number || index == array_of_invoice_number.size - 1)
          index_number, need_increase_previous_number = increase_number(array_of_invoice_number, index_number, index)
        elsif need_increase_previous_number && index_number =~ /\A.+([\-\/\.]{1}\d+)\z/
          index_number = special_auto_increase_number(index_number)
        end

        array_of_invoice_number[index] = index_number.to_s
      end

      array_of_invoice_number.join(special_character)
    rescue
      raise 'unexpected'
    end
  end

  def get_special_character(matching_parts)
    matching_parts.to_a.last.split('').first
  end

  def increase_number(array_of_invoice_number, index_number, index)
    # this method returns index number and need_increase_previous_number value
    # need_increase_previous_number receives true or false value to indicate that need to increase the previous part of invoice number or not

    if (array_of_invoice_number[index - 1] =~ /\A\d+\z/) || (array_of_invoice_number[index - 1] =~ /\A.+([\-\/\.]{1}\d+)\z/)
      max_index_number = ("1" * index_number.size).to_i * 9

      if (index_number.to_i + 1) <= max_index_number
        need_increase_previous_number = false
        [index_number.to_i + 1, need_increase_previous_number]
      else
        need_increase_previous_number = true
        [0, need_increase_previous_number]
      end
    else
      need_increase_previous_number = false
      [
        index_number.to_i + 1,
        need_increase_previous_number
      ]
    end
  end

  def set_creditor_id
    self.creditor_id = company.creditor_id
  end

  def set_bank_fields
    if debit_payment? && other_company.present?
      other_company_bank_account = other_company.bank_account_for_debits
      if other_company_bank_account.present?
        self.debitable_bank_account_owner = other_company_bank_account.owner
        self.debitable_bank_account_number = other_company_bank_account.account_number
        self.debitable_bank_name = other_company_bank_account.bank_name
        self.debitable_bank_number = other_company_bank_account.bank_number
      end
    end
  end

  def direct_debit_only_when_bank_account
    errors.add(:paid_via, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.out_invoice.attributes.paid_via')) if paid_via == 'no_bank_account'
  end
end
```

*Controller:*

```
class Home::OutInvoicesController < Home::InvoicesController
  before_action :service_level_is_free?
  before_action :service_level_is_advanced?, only: [:duplicate]
  before_action :strip_placeholder_and_fitaf_id, only: [:create, :update]

  def new
    @title = t('titles.out_invoices.new')
    @company = current_company
    @out_invoice = OutInvoice.find_by(id: params[:id]) || OutInvoice.new(company: @company) # build ?
    @out_invoice.apply_standard_vat_rate
    @out_invoice.number = @out_invoice.generate_number
  end

  def duplicate
    redirect_to new_home_company_out_invoice_path(id: params[:id])
  end

  def create
    fix_number(out_invoice_params[:net])
    @company = current_company
    @out_invoice = OutInvoice.new # build?
    @out_invoice.assign_attributes(out_invoice_params)
    @out_invoice.proposal = false
    fix_to_be_paid(@out_invoice)
    placeholder_allowed = check_advanced_service_level(current_company) if out_invoice_params[:placeholder].present?
    # not there or placeholder allowed
    if out_invoice_params[:placeholder].andand.empty? || placeholder_allowed
      if @out_invoice.save
        redirect_to home_company_invoices_path(current_company), notice: t('out_invoice.created')
      else
        render :new
      end
    else
      service_level_is_advanced?(t('service_level.required.placeholder'))
    end
  end

  def edit
    @out_invoice = current_company.out_invoices.find(params[:id])
    @title = t('titles.out_invoices.edit')
    @company = current_company
  end

  def update
    fix_number(out_invoice_params[:net])
    @out_invoice = current_company.out_invoices.find(params[:id])
    raise "No love for hackers! Changing a frozen out_invoice is not allowed! Invoice ID: #{@out_invoice.id}. This should not happened." if @out_invoice.frozenn?
    fix_to_be_paid(@out_invoice)
    placeholder_allowed = check_advanced_service_level(current_company) if out_invoice_params[:placeholder].present?
    # placeholder allowed or not there
    if out_invoice_params[:placeholder].empty? || placeholder_allowed
      if @out_invoice.update(out_invoice_params)
        redirect_to home_company_invoices_path, notice: t('out_invoice.updated')
      else
        @company = @out_invoice.company
        render :edit
      end
    else
      service_level_is_advanced?(t('service_level.required.placeholder'))
    end
  end

  def show
    @out_invoice = current_company.out_invoices.find(params[:id])
    @title = "#{t('titles.out_invoices.show')} #{@out_invoice.number}"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render template: "home/out_invoices/pdf.html.erb",
               pdf: @out_invoice.pdf_name
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def fix_to_be_paid(invoice)
    invoice.to_be_paid = Date.today if invoice.paid_today
  end

  def out_invoice_params
    params.require(:out_invoice)
          .permit(
            :company_id,
            :currency,
            :custom_text,
            :cycle,
            :debitable_bank_account_number,
            :debitable_bank_account_owner,
            :debitable_bank_name,
            :debitable_bank_number,
            :durable,
            :durable_until,
            :eur_object_id,
            :internal_note,
            :issuing_date,
            :net,
            :number,
            :other_company_city_str,
            :other_company_fitaf_id,
            :other_company_name_str,
            :other_company_postal_code_str,
            :other_company_street_and_no_str,
            :paid_today,
            :paid_via,
            :physical_copy,
            :placeholder,
            :privately_paid,
            :service_description,
            :to_be_paid,
            :vat_rate
          )
  end

  def strip_placeholder_and_fitaf_id
    out_invoice_params[:placeholder].strip! if out_invoice_params[:placeholder].present?
    out_invoice_params[:other_company_fitaf_id].strip! if out_invoice_params[:other_company_fitaf_id].present?
  end
end
```

*View 1 (calling partial below)*

```
<%= link_to t('common.buttons.back'), home_company_invoices_path(id: current_company) %>
<h1>
  <%= t('out_invoice.new.title') %>
</h1>
<%= render 'form', path: home_company_out_invoices_path(current_user.accounting_company), action: :new %>
```

*View 2 - partial*

```
<%= simple_form_for @out_invoice, url: path do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <% if @out_invoice.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h4>
                <%= t('activerecord.errors.models.invoice.prohibited_save', count: @out_invoice.errors.count) %>
              </h4>
              <ul>
                <% @out_invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= t('out_invoice.form.not_frozen')%>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.hidden_field :company_id, value: current_user.accounting_company.id %>
            <%= f.label :other_company_fitaf_id, t('out_invoice.form.other_company_fitaf_id') %>
            <%= f.text_field :other_company_fitaf_id, class: 'form-control select2 w-50' %>
          </div>
          <% if options_for_place_holders.present? %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :placeholder, t('out_invoice.form.placeholder') %>
              <%= t('in_invoice.form.placeholder_hint') %><br>
              <%= f.select :placeholder, options_for_place_holders, include_blank: true, class: 'form-control select2' %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div>
            <%= f.label :other_company_name_str, t('out_invoice.form.other_company_name_str') %>
            <%= f.text_field :other_company_name_str, required: true, class: 'form-control select2 w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :other_company_street_and_no_str, t('out_invoice.form.other_company_street_and_no_str') %>
            <%= f.text_field :other_company_street_and_no_str, required: true, class: 'form-control select2 w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :other_company_postal_code_str, t('out_invoice.form.other_company_postal_code_str') %>
            <%= f.text_field :other_company_postal_code_str, required: true, class: 'form-control select2 w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :other_company_city_str, t('out_invoice.form.other_company_city_str') %>
            <%= f.text_field :other_company_city_str, required: true, class: 'form-control select2 w-50' %>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :number %>
            <%= f.text_field :number, required: true, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :service_description, t('out_invoice.form.service_description') %>
            <%= f.text_field :service_description, required: true, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :custom_text, t('out_invoice.form.custom_text') %>
            <%= f.text_area :custom_text, required: true, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :internal_note %>
            <%= f.text_field :internal_note, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :net %>
            <div class="input-group w-50">
              <%= f.text_field :net,
                required: true,
                class: 'form-control text-right' %>
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 40px;">€</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            <%= hidden_field(:invoice, :currency, value: 'EUR') %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :vat_rate, t('out_invoice.form.vat_rate') %>
              <div class="input-group  w-50">
                <%= f.text_field :vat_rate,
                                 required: true,
                                 class: 'form-control text-right',
                                 type: 'number' %>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 40px;">%</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% if @company.is_eur? %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :eur_object, t('out_invoice.form.eur_object') %>
              <div class="input-group w-50">
                <% options = options_from_collection_for_select(EurObject.incomes, 'id', 'name') %>
                <%= f.select :eur_object_id, options, include_blank: true %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :issuing_date, t('out_invoice.form.issuing_date') %>
              <div class="input-group">
                <%= f.input :issuing_date, as: :date, html5: true, label: false %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :physical_copy %>
              <% if @out_invoice.physical_copy.attached? %>
                <%= link_to @out_invoice.physical_copy.filename, rails_blob_path(@out_invoice.physical_copy, disposition: 'attachment') %>
              <% end %>
              <%= f.file_field :physical_copy, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
              <h2>
                <%= t('out_invoice.form.payment_area.title')%>
              </h2>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :paid_via, t('out_invoice.form.payment_area.paid_via') %>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <%= f.select :paid_via, Payment.payment_methods(current_company), include_blank: true %>
                </div>
                <% if MeanOfPayment::BankAccount.for_out_invoice(current_company).present? %>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <h3><%= t('out_invoice.form.payment_area.debit_title')%></h3>
                  </div>
                  <small><%= t('out_invoice.form.payment_area.debit_statement')%></small>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :debitable_bank_account_owner %>
                    <%= f.text_field :debitable_bank_account_owner, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :debitable_bank_account_number %>
                    <%= f.text_field :debitable_bank_account_number, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :debitable_bank_name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :debitable_bank_name, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :debitable_bank_number %>
                    <%= f.text_field :debitable_bank_number, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :to_be_paid, t('out_invoice.form.to_be_paid') %>
              <div class="input-group">
                <%= f.input :to_be_paid, as: :date, html5: true, label: false %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :paid_today, t('out_invoice.form.paid_today') %>
              <div class="input-group">
                <%= f.check_box :paid_today %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="form-group">
            <h2><%= t('out_invoice.form.durable_invoice_heading') %></h2>
            <%= f.label :durable, t('out_invoice.form.durable') %> <%= f.check_box :durable %><br><br>
            <%= f.label :cycle, t('out_invoice.form.durable_cycle') %> <%= f.text_field :cycle, class: 'form-control w-50' %><br><br>
            <%= f.label :durable_until, t('out_invoice.form.durable_until') %>
            <%= f.input :durable_until, as: :date, html5: true, label: false %><br><br>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="form-group">
            <% button_title = t('out_invoice.form.button_submit.new') if action == :new %>
            <% button_title = t('out_invoice.form.button_submit.edit') if action == :edit %>
            <%= f.submit button_title, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you're asking us to help debug your code without showing us your code! What you need to do is the tough slog of inserting breakpoints and figuring out why this html element has a disable attribute (if indeed it does... I have no way to know, certainly not from the screenshot)

Comment: @LesNightingill will add the code one test above later an inform you here.

I wrote: "Does anybody know why my forms out of a sudden gets deactivated during tests while it works locally and my test servers? Happy to provide more information. First time I am asking regarding tests. By the way: The tests were fully functional before." but I assume you cant answer this out of the box

Comment: @LesNightingill
added the code for the one cucumber test I posted. see Update 11.09.2023

Comment: ha! that's a case of "be careful what you ask for"! At first you showed no code, now you show waaaay too much. We can't possibly wade through all that. Also there might be javascript in the code that is disabling the element. You need to do the debugging procedures... add breakpoints and find out why the element is being disabled. I would suggest opening a new git branch and piece-by-piece eliminating extraneous stuff until you're down to the absolute bare minimum of the single problematic element on the page.

Comment: @LesNightingill that was my fear :-)
I hate JS so there is no JS in place! Easy :-)

Not sure how I should debug this. Where the heck can disabling come from in tests? Again: Executing the test manually works fully fine so there must be something in cucumber changing the behaviour of the form. Again: Not sure how I should debug this! Any idea?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the view `<%- debugger %>` and then when it breaks, type the line that renders the problematic element and look at what is going to be rendered... does it have a disabled attribute?

Comment: @LesNightingill thanks for the tipp (Nothing to vote up for though. Sorry!)! Will do later and report back! Didnt think of something so simple! :-)

Comment: didnt try yet but isnt it `<% debugger %>` without a `-` ?